# how do i implement methods for a template class that can be either char or string?

Tags: c++, class, templates

i have this class

```
template <typename T>
class B{
    T x;
public:
    B(char c){
        if(typeid(x)==typeid(char)) x=c;
        else{
            string h;
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++) h.push_back(c);
            x=h;
        }
    }
};
```

it is a sample class, if the type of x is char i want x=c while if x is a string i want x to be [c]^10

then i try to create two objects:

```
int main(){
    B<string> a('f');
    B<char> b('g');     
}
```

when i object b is instantiated, the compiler generates an error on the line 10 :

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment
```

i understand the error comes from the fact that you cant assign a string to a char, but i need the task done anyways, how can i do it?

Comment: This looks more like two different classes than a template.

Comment: what should happen if `T` is not a `char` and not a `std::string`?

Comment: @MarekR: template doesn't have to handle all types, even `std::uniform_real_distribution` can only handle `float`/`double`/`long double`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm aware of that templates are using duck typing. More details of the problem can lead to more suitable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre C++17, this seems like the easiest possibility:

```cpp
#include <string>

template<class T>
class B {
    T x;
public:

    B(char c);
};

template<>
B<char>::B(char c) : x(c) {}

template<>
B<std::string>::B(char c) : x(std::string(c,10)) {}

int main() {
    B<char> a('a');
    B<std::string> b('b');
    //B<int> c('c'); // Linker error
}
```

Comment: The highest voted would work too if you specified C++17 using `-std=c++17` as a compiler flag, assuming your compiler supports C++17. I bring this up because your statement implies the C++17 solution doesn't work; it does. It's on you to actually specify the standard, though.

Answer (score 7):

With C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
    T x;
public:
    explicit B(char c)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>) {
            x = c;
        } else {
            // static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>);
            x = std::string(10, c);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: If you're at C++17, `std::is_same_v<T, char>` can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

> if the type of x is char i want x=c while if x is a string i want x to be [c]^10

One way to do that would to be to create a function template that returns the right object.

```
// Declare the function template.
template <typename T> T make_data(char c);

Define specializations of the function template.
template <> char make_data<char>(char c)
{
   return c;
}

template <> make_data<std::string>(char c)
{
   return std::string(c, 10);
}
```

Use them to implement `B`.

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
   T x;
   public:
   B(char c) : x(make_data<T>(c)) {}
};
```

Comment: i can't define more functions, methods, or members

Comment: @GuglielmoLaMastra, that's a rather unusual constraint. At least know that when you are out in the world, such constraints are unlikely to be imposed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple old fashioned template specialization:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class B
{
    T x;
public:
    explicit B(char c) : x(c)
    {}
};

template <>
B<std::string>::B(char c) : x(10, c)
{}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/5klGI0poD9mor4WY